# Let priviledged users add an Icon on Tag

Tags: feature-request

Let's take the exemple of the tag named "dell". A nice thing would be to allow users, with a minimum number of reputation, for instance 500 rep, to assign icon on tag.

If I had the right to, I could add an icon like this on the tag:

[image: Dell Logo]

Which gives something like this (or so):

[image]

Or course it's ugly for now, but you get the idea :)

Comment: I think icons on tags are reserved for advertisers. The mSO proposal [of roughly the same idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106157/allow-icons-on-tags-not-only-for-sponsors) was not well received.

Comment: Didn't knew... :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: You may be interested in a [userscript which can alter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24480/script-to-add-more-branded-icons-to-so-tags-to-offset-adobe-branding) the tag icons per your customization.

Comment: Why would you want to? I don't see what problem this solves.

Comment: Even if I agreed with this idea (I don't) I'd prefer to see the minimum rep set at something more like 500,000 rather than 500.

Answer (score 12):

These icons are [paid for by companies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) wanting to sponsor as another way of generating revenue for the Stack Exchange company.

Personally, I hate the icons and wouldn't complain if I never saw another one ever again.

Answer (score 3):

I always [hated the "rg" tags.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/373/are-the-rg-tags-getting-out-of-control-on-serverfault)   Most of the time you'd see that on a tag, the company had no product with any possible connection to the tag or the question.